# How to get JSON back from HTTP POST Request (to another domain)

Tags: asp.net, api, post, request

I'm trying to use the API on a website, here's the part of the manual:

**Authenticated Sessions** (taken from [here](http://my.amee.com/developers/wiki/Authentication#AuthenticatedSessions))

To create an authenticated session, you need to request an authToken from the '/auth' API resource.

- URL: http://stage.amee.com/auth **(this is not my domain)**
- Method: POST
- Request format: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
- Response format: application/xml, application/json
- Response code: 200 OK
- Response body: Details of the authenticated user, including API
  version.
- Extra data: "authToken" cookie and header, containing the
  authentication token that should be
  used for subsequent calls.

  Parameters: username / password

### Example

#### Request

POST /auth HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/xml
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

username=my_username&password=my_password

#### Response

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Set-Cookie:   authToken=1KVARbypAjxLGViZ0Cg+UskZEHmqVkhx/Pm...;
authToken:   1KVARbypAjxLGViZ0Cg+UskZEHmqVkhx/PmEvzkPGp...==
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8

#### QUESTION:

How do I get that to work?

**I tried jQuery, but it seems to have problem with XSS.** Actual code snippet would be greatly appreciated.

### p.s.

All I was looking for was [WebClient](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/69261/you-can-use-the-webclient.aspx) class in C#

Answer (score 2):

You need to put **application/json** in your **Accept** header, this tells the server you want it to respond in that format - not xml.

Comment: where do i edit the header? i've got an ASPX page, and let's say i need to show the authToken (returned from the post) in a label on that page, how do i do that?

Comment: Sorry I don't know anything about ASPX.  Generally you just call something like request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json") or request.setContentType(...).

Answer (score 2):

I am using rails to extract the same authentication token cookie from stage.amee.com/auth as mentioned above.  it took a bit of experimentation before I created and customised the correct request object that returned a 200 OK, with the authtoken as a cookie.  i haven't found an effective method of reading the request object or I would post exactly what it looks like.  here is my ruby code from the app's controller

```
#define parameters
uri=URI.parse('http://stage.amee.com')
@path = '/auth'
@login_details = 'username=your_username&password=your_password'
@headers = {'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Accept' => 'application/json'}

#create request object
req = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

#send the request using post, defining the path, body and headers
resp, data = req.post(@path, @login_details, @headers)

#print response details to console
puts "response code = " << resp.code
puts "response inspect = " << resp.inspect
resp.each do |key, val| 
  puts "response header key : " + key + " = " + val 
end 
puts "data: " + data
```